# jQuery - Reset all font sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a piece of code that increase the font size on click, decrease the font size on click and reset the font size on click. I am applying this to all fonts via this way:

```
function convertAndApplyFonts(y) {
    $("body").find("*").each(function () {

        if (y == 'increase') {
            $(this).css({
                "font-size": parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) + 1
            });
        }

        if (y == 'decrease') {
            $(this).css({
                "font-size": parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) - 1
            });
        }

        if (y == 'reset') {
            var i = 0;
            $(this).css({
                "font-size": array[i]
            });

            i++;
        }

    });
}
```

And at the beginning of my code I have an array with the original sizes:

```
var array = [];

$("body").find("*").each(function () {
    array.push($(this).css("font-size"));
});
```

My problem is the array I generate at the beginning, does not match the element when I loop through when y == reset.

I have done `console.log()` in my first `foreach` and in reset `foreach` as well and they font-sizes do not match up...What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried the following:

```
$("html").css({"font-size": counter + "em"});
```

but this did nothing.

Comment: The `i` is always 0?

Comment: Thanks wuxiandiejia, that helped a little, but didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through all the elements for something like that is not right at all.

Why can't you use `rem` instead of `px`? That would be a lot easier for you & the browser itself. Using `rem` units you can reach that behaviour in a single line of code, just by modifying the `html` tag (root element) `font-size`, all the other elements that have their font-size / paddings etc. expressed in `rem` instead of `px` will automatically be resized.

Comment: How would I use rem instead of px? Can I see an example?

Comment: I've tried this...$("html").css({"font-size": counter + "em"}); but nothing changes....at all

Comment: Set the font size at root level, on the html element. `html {font-size: 15px;}` And for p elements for example, specify font-size as 1rem (will compute to 15px), h1 as 4rem (will compute to 60px), h2 as 3.5rem (will compute to 52.5px) etc., then, you just change the font-size of html with jQuery and everything else will resize accordingly.